# Fluid simulation stuck

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am new to blender. I am trying to make a simulation of a fluid that comes out from a pipe. However, it looks like it's stuck at the pipe, even though some of fluid comes out. Its weird.

My pipe has the `solidify` modifier and one face deleted for the fluid to come out. It has only fluid physics enabled, with the following settings:

- Type: obstacle
- Volume initialization: both
- No export animation
- Slip type: partial slip (amount:0.2), impact (factor:1)

My icosphere has physics enabled for fluid:

- Type:inflow
- Enabled
- Volume initialization: volume
- No export animation
- No local coordinates
- Inflow velocity: (x:-1, y:0, z:0)

[The Blender file is available for download.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nfNSxu7kw--gjRHSPbjBog1mWa0BEc_F)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the fluid simulation objects were scaled in Object mode instead of Edit mode, and the scales haven't been applied using [Ctrl] + [a]
Also for a large domain you should probably start out with a resolution of at least 100.

Here's a blend file with the applied scales:

[image]